# Question on oft used notation

Tags: functions, notation

What does $(\cdot)$ mean? I have seen this used often, but don't know what it means and when it is used, and I want to make sure I'm not making incorrect assumptions.
For example, I'm reading about copula functions in statistics. There is a function denoted as $c(F1(\cdot), F2(\cdot))$. So, how should this be read, in words?

Comment: I would read it as though it is reminding the reader that $F_1$ and $F_2$ are technically functions which take inputs (*possibly multiple inputs at a time*), but are specifically leaving out the inputs while writing it.  It would be just as correct to write it as $c(F_1,F_2)$.  The difference to writing it as $c(F_1(\cdot),F_2(\cdot))$ is just that it strongly emphasizes that $F_1,F_2$ are functions.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks @JMoravitz

Comment: @JMoravitz. Maybe that should be submitted as answer?